# How to make call out to secured web service

Tags: web-services, https, wsdl, biztalk

Am receiving the message "System.Net.WebException: The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'." when trying to call the web service at "https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php" using BizTalk 2013.

I've imported the wsdl directly from the site, creating the schemas and the bindings to make the call. The Send port is set up as WCF-BasicHttp, Security Mode: Transport, Transport Client Credential Type: None. I'm able to call the service using SOAP-UI from the BizTalk server, providing no form of authentication.

Have read numerous posts and documentation, but nothing I've done to this point has helped. I'm sure I'm missing something; just not sure what that something is!

Comment: Do you have a proxy server?

Comment: None is specified in the send port, no. "Use Send Handler proxy settings" is selected. WCF-BasicHttp has no proxy settings specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of the WSDL: `<soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>` it's an RPC type web service

Like the documentation [specifies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/what-are-the-wcf-adapters): 'The WCF adapters **do not support consuming Remote Procedure Call (RPC)-style Web services** because the message parts in RPC-style Web services are referring to the message types rather than the message elements where WCF adapters are using elements for the message parts. We recommend that you add the RPC-style Web services through Add Web Reference wizard for consuming the Web services in BizTalk projects.'